# List of SOAP Function in Non-WSDL Mode

Tags: php, soap

I am using the following code to read attendance data from a biometric device:

```
<?php

$options = array(
    'location' => 'http://192.168.1.178/iWsService',
    'uri' => 'http://www.zksoftware/Service/message/'
);

$client = new SoapClient(null, $options);
$soapRequest = "<GetAttLog><ArgComKey xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">0</ArgComKey><Arg><PIN xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">All</PIN></Arg></GetAttLog>";
$response = $client->__doRequest($soapRequest, 'http://192.168.1.178/iWsService', '', '1.1');
echo '<pre>', var_dump(htmlspecialchars($response, ENT_QUOTES)), '</pre>';

?>
```

This just works fine. But since we do not have the `documentation/manual/API Reference` for this particular device (and nowhere available), I have no clue on what other functions are available in this machine.

Is there any luck finding out what other SOAP parameters this device could accept?

Your help would be really valuable at this moment. Thank you!

Comment: `var_dump($client->__getFunctions(),$client->__getTypes())` not helps?

Comment: @SergeyRatnikov - Those commands are only for WSDL.

Comment: Which type of ZK supporting SOAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. WSDL is the source of information about functions and arguments. No WSDL - no function list.

Answer (score 4):

At last I found the SOAP SDK Manual of `zksoftware`.

Since I was searching for the manual for almost a year, I am uploading it to my server for the benefit of future users:
http://www.myfurni.com/downloads/zksoftware_SOAPSDKManual.pdf

### Edit:

The above link doesn't work anymore. Here is the new one:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByvozREXZpckcHlHYnZoOTMtWjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore, do you still have it?

Comment: @matt.j.crawford - Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByvozREXZpckcHlHYnZoOTMtWjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Google Drive link is also not opening any pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://dnaextrim.github.io/php_zklib/)  It uses the UDP protocol to communicate to the Attendance Machine.